# How to rotate original image without resizing(not expand width or height) the image

Tags: iphone

I have rotate the image using [`UIRotationGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIRotateGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and it's working fine. But the image width & height increased.

**Original** Image Size: x = *85.000000*, y = *83.000000*, width = *150.000000*, height = *150.000000*
**After** rotating image size : x = *54.476551*, y = *52.476551*, width = *211.046906*, height = *211.046906*

How to handle this problem? I am trying like this:

```
recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.rotation);
recognizer.rotation = 0;
```

Comment: simply rotate it then dont use the UIGesture ...

Comment: I need rotation gesture. So that only I used.

Comment: ImageView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / -2); this worked for me and there is no change in the image size....

Comment: Using your code, Is it possible to user rotate the image and change the scale of the image?

Comment: For scaling u gotta use the gesture ... this will only help u rotate the image on one point....

Comment: I already tried this. Any way thanks for your precise response. Any idea about this please inform me.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGAffineTransform transform = self.view.transform;
            if (UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft == deviceOrientation) {
                transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -(M_PI / 2.0));
            } else {
                transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0);
            }
            self.view.transform = transform;
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks matheszabi. Using your code Is it possible to user can change the image rotation? I think it is static rotation. I want user to interact the image.

Comment: just change the self to your variable, like rotation, need to adapt. Sorry if doesn't match 1000% of your needs, and doesn't help you at all